# final_response must be set

Tags: javascript, node.js, actions-on-google

I am trying to do implement a list response, this is just sample code but It's not working, webhook is enabled, deploying done,please see this code and recommend good solution for this. I don't know the exact answer of this question. try trying like.The error is

MalformedResponse

'final_response' must be set.

:(

```js
'use strict'

const {dialogflow, List ,Image}=require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
//const d=require('date-and-time');
const app=dialogflow({debug : true });
let date = new Date();

app.intent('what is',(conv,{menu})=>{
//conv.ask('This is today menu ');
conv.ask(new List({
      title : "Today's Menu",
      items : {
        'one':{
          synonyms:[
          'show me Chinese',
          'Chinese',
        ],
        title : 'Chinese menu',
        description : 'chow(30/-), manchurian(50/-),hakka chow(80/-)',
        image : new Image({
          url : 'https://image.ibb.co/fBNYT9/image.png',
          alt : 'chinese food',
        }),
      },
      'two' : {
        synonyms:[
        'show me Veg',
        'Veg',
      ],
      title : 'Veg menu',
      description : 'chow(30/-), manchurian(50/-),hakka chow(80/-)',
      image : new Image({
        url : 'https://image.ibb.co/fBNYT9/image.png',
        alt : 'chinese food',
      }),
    },
    'three' : {
      synonyms:[
        'show me non Veg',
        'non Veg',
        ],
    title : 'non Veg menu',
    description : 'fake description',
    image : new Image({
              url : 'https://image.ibb.co/fBNYT9/image.png',
              alt : 'chinese food',
          }),
      },
    },
  }));
});


//response from upper layer.

const SELECTION_KEY_ONE='one',SELECTION_KEY_TWO='two',SELECTION_KEY_THREE='three';



// );

const selected_item_response ={
  [SELECTION_KEY_ONE]: 'You choose to eat chinese',
  [SELECTION_KEY_TWO] : 'Hey Its Veg Time',
  [SELECTION_KEY_THREE] :'NON veg timeeeeee',
}
app.intent('action.intent.OPTION',(conv,params,option)=>{
  let response='you did not selected any option';
  if(option && selected_item_response.hasOwnProperty(option)){
    response=selected_item_response[option];
  }
  conv.close(response);
});
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Why did you comment out the conv.ask with the string? Rich responses should also include some text. But you should also check firebase logs to see if your fulfillment is crashing with an error.

Comment: add the logs from the server

Comment: severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "MalformedResponse: 'final_response' must be set"  
 timestamp: "2018-08-13T06:29:56.826567243Z"  
 trace: "projects/332867731471/traces/1534141786258"  
}

Comment: It would help us a lot if you updated the original question with logs from your webhook running and cutting and pasting the entire contents of the "request", "response" and "debug" tabs in the simulator when you have the problem.

Comment: Are you sending this to a phone? You need "display" capabilities. Are you using the simulator?